# asp Textbox visible property always true in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-4.0

I have below code :

**aspx:**

```
<% Dim AccountID  As Integer
  AccountID  = 200
  If AccountID <> 202 And AccountID <> 203 Then
       txtChequeNo.Visible = False 
  Else %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtChequeNo" Visible="true" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>
<% End If %>
```

**aspx.vb**

In button click event block in code behind :

```
If txtChequeNo.Visible = true Then 

// Validation Block

End if
```

My question is , AccoundID value is 200 Then textbox not visible in browser .

But Validation Block is always execute.

I cant identify the reason.. Anybody have clue..?

Comment: Side-note: use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` as default instead of `And` and `Or`. Also, `If txtChequeNo.Visible Or txtChequeNo.Visible = true` this is the same condition, the last is just the verbose version and redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It makes perfect sense.

You are having this problem because you are using server tags in the aspx file so your code is executed line-by-line.

Your code is executed 1st but you never see the result because directly beneath you are always setting the visibility using `Visible="true"`

Also you need to revise your coding altogether. You are placing your asp:textbox in the else clause? What are you trying to achieve?

Using your coding logic I would write the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtChequeNo" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>
<%
    Dim AccountID  As Integer
    AccountID  = 200

    If AccountID <> 202 And AccountID <> 203 Then
        txtChequeNo.Visible = False 
    Else
        txtChequeNo.Visible = True
    End If
%>
```

I am creating the textbox 1st without setting any value for visibility (it will true by defaylt) and then changing the visibility with code.